# Passing argument to c# callback from c++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Below is my code in c#...

here callback is too implemented in c# only.
i want a callback from c++ dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


class Program
{
  //   [DllImport("C:/Users/kool/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/DLL/Debug/DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        function1(function2);   // i want thia function2 to be fetched from ++ dll

    }

    public delegate void fPointer(); // point to every functions that it has void as return value and with no input parameter 
    public static void function1(fPointer ftr)
    {
        fPointer point = new fPointer(ftr);
        point();
    }
    public static void function2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bla");
    }
}
```

i will createa a dLL from where i will send function2 to

```
function1(function2);
```

how can i implement it??

Answer (score 0):

One way is exporting the C# assembly as a type library and using it from C++ as if it were a COM component.

Use TlbExp.exe in the Visual Studio command prompt to export the C# assembly as a type library. Then register the type library with RegAsm.exe. Then in the C++ code use the #import directive to import the type library. You can now use the C# classes from C++ as if they were COM classes.

For more detail see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172270.aspx

Edit: Sorry, which is it that you want to do: use C++ from C#, or use C# from C++?

Either one is possible. The link above explains how to use C# from C++. This one explains how to use C++ from C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6tx9dw3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can send pointer to your managed .net function and call it from unmamaged code (callback).

Detail here http://habrahabr.ru/post/130690/ (use google to translate it from russian if needed, but you need to look at last two code example).

Also check your code calling - it should comply on both managed and unmanaged sides (use __*stdcall* in C-code and *CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl* in *DllImport* attribute).